# Extjs 6 uxiframe under items of panel is not scrollable in IOS10 IPad

Tags: ios, ipad, extjs, scroll

I am working in Sencha Extjs 6.1 where i need to load document (pdf) in uxiframe, its working fine (scrolling) with IOS version below 10, but not in IOS 10 Ipad. it stuck it after small scroll of pdf page, but in IOS below 10 it scroll to complete page.

Following is my code :

```
Ext.define('MapViewer.view.main.HTMLPanel.HTMLPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
xtype: 'htmlpanel',
height:300,
header: false,
style: '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;',
requires: ['MapViewer.view.main.HTMLPanel.HTMLPanelController'],
controller: 'htmlpanelcontroller',
tbar: {
    items: [
        {
            cls: 'selectedButtonCls',
            reference: 'iframePlanTekst',
            itemId: 'iframePlanTekst',
            header: false,
            //glyph: 'xe902@icomoon', // plantekst
            iconCls: 'icon-viewer_plantekst',
            listeners: {
                click: 'onButtonClick'
            }
        },
         {
             reference: 'iframeDiagram',
             itemId: 'iframeDiagram',
             header: false,
             hidden: true,
             //glyph: 'xe901@icomoon', // diagram
             iconCls: 'icon-viewer_diagram',
             listeners: {
                 click: 'onButtonClick'
             }
         }

    ]
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'uxiframe',
        height: '99%',
        cls:'textTouchCss',
        itemId: 'htmluxpanel',
        style: 'padding:10px 10px 5px 10px',
        reference: 'htmluxpanel',
        header: false
    }
]
```

});

Where cls : textTouchCss is like:

> .textTouchCss{
>       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important; overflow: scroll !important;
>   }

putting scrollable: true or scrollable :'y' will freezes the panel.

I am loading the path in uxiframe like

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("htmlpanel")[0].down('#htmluxpanel').load(path);
```

Can any one has idea, what should be done to make this scroll better in IOS 10 ? Please help. 
thanks